# How can I fix my npm start script?

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm

I am trying to run my node.js app on heroku in production, and on my local machine in development. After some tinkering I got it to stop crashing on heroku by changing my start script in the package.json file from this:

```
"export NODE_ENV=development; node server.js"
```

to this:

```
"node server.js"
```

However, now it crashes when I try to run it in development. How can I make it so that it only sets the NODE_ENV to development if it has not already been set to production by heroku?

Answer (score 0):

If you are in windows:

```
SET NODE_ENV=production
```

For heroku , The NODE_ENV environment variable is set to 'production’ by default, but you can set it to any arbitrary string:

```
heroku config:set NODE_ENV=staging
```